# How to host a database online

Tags: python, mysql, database, google-cloud-platform

I am building a desktop application using pyQt which will store, update and retrieve data from an online database so that the users can access data remotely.

Now my question is how do implement it? Which database to use (e.g. MySQL, SQL etc.)? Where should I host my database (I don't want a free hosting site because of safety concerns, this application is meant for production purposes)?

Also I would like to know how to connect to a database hosted online; for explanation purpose consider an example that I've hosted a MySQL database on Google Cloud, now how do I connect to this online MySQL database hosted on Google Cloud? and are the commands for query, update etc. same just like when you use MySQL on localhost?

I'm new to this online database hosting thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not a database expert, but have been doing something similar to you so here's what I've found in my own research!

## Database Selection

As for the what database should you use, that is going to be application specific, though for most standard applications any of the main SQL architectures (SQL and Postgresql) will be sufficient. Note that SQLite doesn't support network access so don't go for that!

If you want to read up more on the differences and advantages of both then you can start here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems

## Database Hosting

There are many online SQL hosts you can choose from. If you're going to be using this in production then I'd lean towards one of the main cloud providers (AWS/GCP/Azure) as they provide easy to deploy, scalable, secure services for this - also you may want to end up using some of their other cloud compute services. To get started pick whichever ever you have most experience with.

## Python Integration

There are several python packages for connecting to and manipulating databases. The basis is that the same commands (CREATE, SELECT, QUERY etc.)  are the same as if you were running it locally, they just provide a wrapper to connect to a database and to write and read from the database. For example you have mysql connector for mySQL databases and psycopg2 for postgres.